# Apache POI header error

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read an xlsx file using Apache POI. Here is my code -

```
public static void convertFromXlsx(File inputFile, File outputFile) {
        StringBuffer bf = new StringBuffer();
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            String strGetValue = "";
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
          //      XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
                org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputFile);
```

java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0000000000000000, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0

Please help me understand why this is happening and how it can be fixed.

There were intially 2 sheets in the xlsx file. I have tried with copies of the file - first removing the 2nd sheet and also by copying and pasting the content into a new sheet as text only but both lead to the same error.

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade and try with the newest version

Comment: It might be also useful if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). My guess is, that InputFile is empty, i.e. ˋWorkbookFactory.create()ˋ needs to be called on an existing .xls/x.

Comment: @kiwiwings New versions of Apache POI give a more helpful error on empty files, if that's what's wrong, partly inspired by questions like this... :)

Comment: Now I am using version 3.15 of POI and POI-OOXML. It is an xlsx file originating on a windows machine. I downloaded it onto a Linux machine where my program is running and now I run into this exception - org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.NotOfficeXmlFileException: No valid entries or contents found, this is not a valid OOXML (Office Open XML) file. I have 2 sheets in the file.

Comment: I have also tried opening the file in libreoffice calc and saving it as an OpenOffice XML (.xlsx) file and on another occasion as a Microsoft Office XML (.xlsx) file

Comment: I was able to debug into ZipEntry.java to find that the exception gets thrown from the point where it gets list of parts from the xlsx file. The exception is thrown by this method - protected PackagePart[] getPartsImpl() throws InvalidFormatException when due to numEntries remaining 0. Have tried opening the xlsx file in archive manager on linux by renaming it as a zip file where I do see xml files for various worksheets and the workbook itself. Strangely also, the same code works when by itself in a separate project i.e. it creates a workbook object.